# Scheduler in Debian (Raspbian)

Tags: debian, raspbian

In what file or files would I find the kernal process scheduler for Debian and/or Raspbian?  I would like to organize some Operating Systems Concepts labs by recompiling the existing scheduler with other experimental schedulers and measure the performance results for a class laboratory assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Debian's kernel is linux (well, usually).

You may start looking there:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sched

Comment: *Usually*? I've never seen a debian with another kernel...

Comment: @chaos Debian GNU/kfreebsd (official port) and Debian GNU/Hurd (unofficial) both use the GNU userspace with a different kernel.

Comment: https://www.debian.org/ports/hurd/
https://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/
I never saw them installed, but they do exist.

Comment: Interessting, didn't knew that.